# Load Data Infile errors

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

In the syntax of load infile data i saw that the fields and line clauses are optional. So I used only character set clause for utf8

Here my sql:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("LOAD DATA INFILE " + filename + " INTO TABLE " + tblname + " CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'", conn);
```

filename is the addresse it's format is:  "E:\Macdata\20131228\atelier.sql"

table name is directly taken from database is as : "atelier"

But I get the error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'E:\Macdata\20131228\atelier.sql INTO TABLE atelier CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'' at line 1

What is the mistake in my query command ?

MYSQLversion is 5.0.10 with XAMPP

After changing the query I begin to receive fatal error number 0 (enclosed filename with ')

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + filename + "' IGNORE INTO TABLE " + tblname + " CHARACTER SET UTF8", conn);
```

My data file has this form which works on phpmyadmin

```
INSERT INTO `atelier` VALUES(1, 'Chateau Carbonnieux -1', '2013-12-26', 23, 10, 0, '4 macarons differents', 'mamie', '2013-12-15 11:09:14', 'sabrina', '2013-12-18 05:29:26');
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your statements is wrong. Quotes are missing in your first statement (see second statement). Check the syntax here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

Some sparse notes:

0 is not a fatal error, it's the code for success.

`IGNORE` handles duplicate rows, not syntax errors.

Comment: I truncate table befores insert. And as I told the which eclose the filnename has supressed the old error. I have a new error now. I try to read the data (this data does the work in phpmyadmin)

Comment: To say all as I am a newbie in mysql i wrote this query by the help of the link that you put in your answer. But the link does not say to enclose the filename with '. For insert or select I don't enclose the variables names with ' but I see that LOAD DATA INFILE requires to enclose filename with '. Fatal error is not named by me it's displayed by mysql exact sentence is : fatal error encountered attemping to read the result set.

Comment: Look better: the syntax is 'file_name'

Comment: Nope beacause when i do intentionally a mistake in filename mysql gives another error and it's not fatal error.  With my last query it tries to read the file (this sql file is loaded by phpmyadin so there is no error) but finishes with the fatal error encountered attemping to read the result set.

Comment: The error you pasted here is 1064, and it's fatal... trust me, all MySQL developers see it several times a day :) Anyway, use the ' and then run SHOW WARNINGS. You will see another fatal error, or (hopefully) all problems in your statement.

Comment: You miss the order of my edit. In my firsy query that's right the error code was 1064 but in the second is ZERO and the error is as I told. If you reread the question you will see AFTER CHANGİNG my query...